# Ruby does not work on user profile page

Tags: feature-request, bug, furigana

When ruby is enabled, we can put hiragana above Kanji characters to show how to read the Kanji characters.

The text editor of user profile lets us preview the ruby as shown in the following screenshot.

> [image]

However, when I save my edit, the ruby is no longer properly rendered. I think that ruby  has not  been enabled on the japanese.stackexchange.com's user profile.

Should we enable ruby on user profile page as well? If yes, should ruby be also enabled on all stackexchange.com subdomains?

Note: This feature request might have no significant benefit for us. But I love every single thing is precisely defined. (wink)

Comment: I can't see why it would be useful. I am a supporter of “less furigana, better world” so ... well. However, the way you describe it feels more like a bug-request than a feature-request, right?

Comment: I have added bug tag to this question. I am not requesting bug for sure.

Comment: yeah the about me on the user profile is not included in ruby processing ->  http://dev.sstatic.net/js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js (search for ` ruby._loop`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a personal feeling that it's always better to implement this feature. It does no harm, and brings us some convenience especially when you're 川内{せんだい}出身 or I'm in the mood for nicknaming myself [緑林白波の猖獗]{クロロフィル・アウトバースト}, but I'm not in hurry :)